# Moving a git server to allow multiple users

Tags: git

I'm running a git server as ec2-user on an Amazon Linux AWS instance, and now I need to allow different users access to different repositories.

I've found instructions to set up a new git server to allow this, but I'd prefer not to have to reimport my current repos if at all possible - is there a migration option?

Thanks.

Comment: How is "reimporting" different from "migrating", really?

Comment: What are you using to host the repositories? Just `ssh`? Gitlab? Gitea? RhodeCode?

Comment: Just ssh... I believe

Comment: Please post a link to the instructions you mention, so that we can get some background on what you're trying to do.